# Buscar caminho do arquivo vindo do input type="file"

Tags: php, html, input

Boa tarde, a algum tempo estou com um problema, tenho o seguinte input do tipo file, para pegar algum arquivo qualquer.

```
<form class="form-signin" method="post" action="?classe=Usuario&acao=pegaFoto">
      <div class="form-label-group">
           <input type="file" name="usuario[foto]" required>
      </div>
      <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block text-uppercase" type="submit">Enviar</button>
<form>
```

Quando clicar para dar submit, ele vai entrar na mesma página, se houver algum arquivo dentro do usuario[foto], ele vai chamar a função pegaFoto() no controller.

```
public function pegaFoto(){
    $usuario = new Usuario();
    if( isset( $_POST['usuario'])){
        $usuario->foto($_POST['usuario']);
        $usuario->pegaFoto();
    }
    require_once 'views/view_foto.php';
}
```

Essa função do controller chama a função pegaFoto() da model e também chama a função foto() onde eu gostaria de guardar o caminho do arquivo.

```
public function foto($usuario){
    $this->foto = $usuario['foto'];
}
public function pegaFoto(){
    //coloquei o echo só para ver o que estava puxando
    echo $this->foto;
}
```

Porém do jeito que fiz, ele só pega o nome do arquivo escolhido, gostaria de saber se de alguma forma eu poderia pegar o caminho do arquivo.

Comment: Arquivos enviados para o PHP ficam em `$_FILES`, não em `$_POST`. Você moveu o arquivo para um local definitivo antes de tratá-lo ou não precisa disso?

Comment: Nunca tinha visto o $_FILES, vou dar uma olhada aqui, não precisa do local definitivo, só queria buscar o caminho por enquanto.

Comment: Para envio de arquivos ( $_FILES ) pelo seu form, adicione na tag <form> o enctype="multipart/form-data", ex: <form action="../../" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primeiro você precisa pegar o arquivo que vem no `$_FILES[ ]`, diferente dos outros tipos de input, os arquivos são enviados para o servidor PHP atravez do $_FILES, com ele você pode recuperar nome, formato, o arquivo em si e etc.

Um exemplo de upload seria assim:

```
//Pegando extensão do arquivo
$extencao = strtolower(substr($_FILES['arquivo']['name'],-4)); 

//Definindo um novo nome para o arquivo
$new_name = "novo_nome_do_arquivo" . $ext; 

//Diretório para uploads
$dir = 'uploads/'; 

// salva o arquivo no dietório
move_uploaded_file($_FILES['arquivo']['tmp_name'], $dir.$new_name);
```

Agora sim  o arquivo foi salvo e o caminho é o que você definiu em `$dir`.

Para saber mais veja a documentação:

https://www.php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php

https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.php